# Confused in join query in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

The following works:

```
  SELECT IBAD.TRM_CODE, IBAD.IPABD_CUR_QTY, BM.BOQ_ITEM_NO, 
         IBAD.BCI_CODE, BCI.BOQ_CODE
    FROM IPA_BOQ_ABSTRCT_DTL IBAD, 
         BOQ_CONFIG_INF BCI,BOQ_MST BM
   WHERE BM.BOQ_CODE = BCI.BOQ_CODE 
     AND BCI.BCI_CODE = IBAD.BCI_CODE
     AND BCI.STATUS = 'Y' 
     AND BM.STATUS = 'Y'  
order by boq_item_no;
```

Results:

[image]

But after joining many tables with that query, the result is confusing:

```
 SELECT  (SELECT CMN_NAME 
            FROM CMN_MST 
           WHERE CMN_CODE= BRI.CMN_RLTY_MTRL) MTRL,
         RRI.RRI_RLTY_RATE AS RATE,
         I.BOQ_ITEM_NO,
         (TRIM(TO_CHAR(IBAD.IPABD_CUR_QTY,
             '9999999999999999999999999999990.999'))) AS IPABD_CUR_QTY,
         TRIM(TO_CHAR(BRI.BRI_WT_FACTOR,
             '9999999999999999999999999999990.999'))  AS WT,
         TRIM(TO_CHAR((IBAD.IPABD_CUR_QTY*BRI.BRI_WT_FACTOR),
             '9999999999999999999999990.999')) AS RLTY_QTY,
         (TRIM(TO_CHAR((IBAD.IPABD_CUR_QTY*BRI.BRI_WT_FACTOR*RRI.RRI_RLTY_RATE),
             '9999999999999999999999990.99'))) AS TOT_AMT,
         I.TRM_CODE AS TRM
  FROM
      (SELECT * FROM ipa_boq_abstrct_dtl) IBAD
INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT * FROM BOQ_RLTY_INF) BRI
          ON IBAD.BCI_CODE = BRI.BCI_CODE 
INNER JOIN
      (SELECT * FROM RLTY_RATE_INF) RRI
          ON BRI.CMN_RLTY_MTRL = RRI.CMN_RLTY_MTRL 
INNER JOIN
      ( SELECT IBAD.TRM_CODE, IBAD.IPABD_CUR_QTY, 
               BM.BOQ_ITEM_NO, IBAD.BCI_CODE, BCI.BOQ_CODE
          FROM IPA_BOQ_ABSTRCT_DTL IBAD, 
               BOQ_CONFIG_INF BCI,BOQ_MST BM
         WHERE 
               BM.BOQ_CODE = BCI.BOQ_CODE 
           AND BCI.BCI_CODE = IBAD.BCI_CODE
           and BCI.status = 'Y' 
          and bm.status = 'Y') I
          ON BRI.BCI_CODE = I.BCI_CODE 
         AND I.TRM_CODE = BRI.TRM_CODE
         AND BRI.TRM_CODE =4
group by BRI.CMN_RLTY_MTRL, RRI.RRI_RLTY_RATE, I.BOQ_ITEM_NO, 
         IBAD.IPABD_CUR_QTY, BRI.BRI_WT_FACTOR, I.TRM_CODE, I.bci_code
order by BRI.CMN_RLTY_MTRL
```

Results:

[image]

`TRM` should be `11` instead of `4` in the first row.

Comment: FYI, whenever you join with a subquery `(SELECT * FROM tablename)`, you could just join with `tablename` instead of the subquery.

Comment: You only select records where `BRI.TRM_CODE =4` and you only join records where `I.TRM_CODE = BRI.TRM_CODE`. So you only get result lines with I.TRM_CODE 4.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner But it's returning a row with `IPABD_CUR_QTY = 3197.280`, which the first query says belongs to `TRM_CODE = 11`. That's what's confusing him.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d1d67/4  DEMO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you getting 4 because you use

```
AND BRI.TRM_CODE =4
```

if you remove this criter you can get true result

Answer (score 1):

In your first query, both of the rows you've highlighted have BCI_CODE=1866.

In the second query, you are joining that result set with a number of others (which come from the same tables, which seems odd). In particular, you are joining from the subquery to another table using BCI_CODE, and from there to `(SELECT * FROM ipa_boq_abstrct_dtl) IBAD`.  Since both of the rows from the subquery have the same BCI_CODE, they will join to the same rows in the other tables.

The quantity that you are actually displaying in the second query is from `(SELECT * FROM ipa_boq_abstrct_dtl) IBAD`, not from the other subquery.

Is the problem simply that you mean to select `I.IPABD_CUR_QTY` instead of `IBAD.IPABD_CUR_QTY`?

You might find this clearer if you did not reuse the same aliases for tables at multiple points in the query.